# Why is my form not validating when submit is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() // Run the function after the DOM is ready
{

    var validForm = true; // Set the variable to be true, assume the form is valid

    // Required field. Cannot be empty, spaces, null or undefinded. Contents of the field cannot contain < or > or '. 
    function validateName() 
    {
        var nameInput = $("#custName").val(); // Create a variable that takes in the value of the field
        var nameEx = new RegExp(/<>^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/); // RegEx of what the field should contain
        var nameTest = nameEx.test(nameInput); // Test the RegEx with the current input

        if(nameInput == "") 
        {
            nameTest = false;
            validForm = false; // Form will be set to false
            var custNameError  = $("#custNameError").html("Please enter a valid name");
        }

        else if (nameInput != "" && !nameTest)
        {
            nameTest = false;
            validForm = false; 
            custNameError  = $("#custNameError").html("Please enter a valid name");
        }

        else 
        {
            custNameError = $("#custNameError").html("");
        }
    };

    // Field is optional. Must be numbers only 
    function validatePhone()
    {
        var phoneInput = $("#custPhone").val();
        var phoneEx = new RegExp(/^[0-9]{10}$/); // 10 digit RegEx from 0-9

        if(phoneEx.test(phoneInput))
        {
            $("#custPhoneError").html("Please enter a valid 10 digit phone number");
            validForm = false;
        }

        else 
        {
            validForm = true;
        }
    };

    // Required field. Can have letters, numbers, symbols, and including @ and . email address. 
    function validateEmail()
    {
        var emailInput = $("#custEmail").val;
        var emailEx = new RegExp (/^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$/);   
        var emailTest = emailEx.text(emailInput);
        var custEmailError = $("#custEmailError").html("");

        if(!emailTest)
        {
            validForm = false;

            if(emailInput == "")
            {
                custEmailError = $("#custEmailError").html("Please enter a valid email address.");
            }

            else 
            {
                if(emailInput != "" && !emailTest)
                {
                    custEmailError = $("#custEmailError").html("Please enter a valid email in the following format: test123@email.com");
                    $("#custEmail").val(emailInput);
                    validForm = true;
                }
            }
        }   
    };

    // Required field. Must select one radio button
    function validateProduct()
    {
        var productInput = $("input[type=radio]:checked").val();

        if (productInput == undefined)
        {
            var productTest = false;
            validForm = false; 
            var custProductError = $("#custProductError").html("Please select a product in regards to your complaint");
        }

        else if (!validForm)
        {
            $("input[type=radio]:checked").val(productInput);
        }

        else 
        {
            productTest = true;
            custProductError = $("#custProductError").html("");
            validForm = true;
        }

    };

    // Required field. Must be longer than 5 characters, can contain basic punctuation symbols
    function validateComplaint()
    {
        var complaintInput = $("#custComplaint").val();
        var complaintEx = new RegExp (/^[a-zA-Z0-9,.!?;" ]{5,}$/);
        var complaintTest = complaintEx.test(complaintInput);
        var complainLengthInput = complaintInput.length;

        if (complainLengthInput < 5)
        {
            validForm = false; 
            var custComplaintError = $("#custComplaintError").html("Please have your complaint to be at least 5 characters long");
            $("#custComplaint").val(complaintInput);
        }

        else if (complaintTest)
        {
            custComplaintError = $("#custComplaintError").html("");
        }

        else 
        {
            if (complainLengthInput >= 5 && !complaintTest)
            {
                custComplaintError = $("#custComplaintError").html("Please describe your complaint in detail. Using letters and numbers.")
                $("#custComplaint").val(complaintInput);
            }
            else 
            {
                validForm = true;
            }`enter code here`
        }
    };

    function submitForm()
    {
        $("#sendForm").click(function()
        {
            validateName();
            validateEmail();
            validatePhone();
            validateProduct();
            validateComplaint();
        });

        $("#resetForm").click(function()
        {
            $("#custNameError").html("");
            $("#custPhoneError").html("");
            $("#custEmailError").html("");
            $("#custProductError").html("");
            $("#custComplaintError").html("");
        });
    };

});
```

HTML:

```
<h2>WDV321 Advanced Javascript </h2>
<h3>Form Validation Project - Complaint Form</h3>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <p>Please enter the following information in order to process your concerns.</p>
  <p> 
    <label for="custName">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="custName" id="custName" />
        <span id="custNameError" class="errorMsg"></span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="custPhone">Phone Number: </label>
        <input type="text" name="custPhone" id="custPhone" />
        <span id="custPhoneError" class="errorMsg"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
    <label for="custEmail">Email: </label>
        <input type="text" name="custEmail" id="custEmail" />
        <span id="custEmailError" class="errorMsg"></span>
  </p>
    <p>Please Select Product Group:</p>
    <span class="error" id="custProductError"></span>
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="custProducts" value="books" id="custProducts_0" />
      Books</label>
    <br />
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="custProducts" value="movies" id="custProducts_1" />
      Movies</label>
    <br />
    <label>
            <input type="radio" name="custProducts" value="electronics" id="custProducts_2" />
            Consumer electronics</label>
    <br />
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="custProducts" value="computer" id="custProducts_3" />
      Computer</label>
    <br />
  </p>
    <p>Description of problem:  (Limit 200 characters)</p>
    <span class="error" id="custComplaintError"></span>
  <p>
```

I am extremely confused on what I am doing wrong. When the submit button is hit, it doesn't seems like its running any of my functions. The console on google chrome isnt giving me any errors, and from what I am reviewing, it doesnt seem like I see any syntax errors. Please advise.

Comment: What's your HTML?

Comment: You have to prevent the default behavior of the form click action first.

Comment: Just posted my html, sorry about that.

Comment: where is your submit button and form close in html ?

Answer (score 0):

```
function submitForm(e) // grab the click event
{
    e.preventDefault();  // prevent default event
    $("#sendForm").click(function()
    {
        validateName();
        validateEmail();
        validatePhone();
        validateProduct();
        validateComplaint();
    });

    $("#resetForm").click(function()
    {
        $("#custNameError").html("");
        $("#custPhoneError").html("");
        $("#custEmailError").html("");
        $("#custProductError").html("");
        $("#custComplaintError").html("");
    });
};
```

Comment: Hi Andre, thanks for the tip. Just tired with you suggested, but still not getting any validations going through.